# Magento 2 Adding Blocks to Custom Page Layouts

Tags: magento2

I have created a new custom page layout in Magento 2.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

I have also created a Block in the backend.

My question is...How can I call the block content into my layout, in other words I want to reference the Block I made in my Layout so that the content of my block will be should in this layout.

Have can I do that?

Tried this - Suggested by krishna:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="topmostMessage">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="topmostMessage" xsi:type="string">quickblock</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
    <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
    <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the static block in layout as described.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="quick-block">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">quickblock</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Change `quickblock` with your static-block identifier.

I have created a small working example

mahento/app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

magento/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

magento/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="module" frontName="module">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

/var/www/m5agento207/app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Vendorcommerce. All rights reserved.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface
     */
    protected $_cacheTypeList;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface
     */
    protected $_cacheState;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool
     */
    protected $_cacheFrontendPool;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface $cacheState
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\StateInterface $cacheState,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
        $this->_cacheState = $cacheState;
        $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Flush cache storage
     *
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();  
        return $this->resultPage;

    }
}
```

magento/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/module_index_index.xml

> In my case i have created CMS block with **test3** identifier and placed in front end layout. Make sure you should replace by your block name.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <body>     
    <!--        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Index\Index" name="index_index" template="index/index.phtml">
            </block>  -->

    <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="quick-block">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">test3</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Run

php magento setup:upgrade

php magento cache:clean

Run url in Browser

http://127.0.0.1/magento/module

Comment: OK, I've tried it and changed the ID but it's not showing...I'd added the code to the question as it's too long to paste here

Comment: use <page tag with  layout="2columns-left" and paste the reference container inside the body, try it one more time by removing cache..)

Comment: Check the updated answer.and make sure your module working fine.

Comment: OK, I've changed it but now it's only showing container.phtml file but not the Block content ... I'm working localhost ... is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Please check the working example added to answer.